# Reading a binary file as an array of bytes or 16 or 32 bits using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am working on ARM-based modem linux host machine and I need to read a bin file as an 8-,16- or 32- bits array. I basically need to encrypt the file in question and was thinking of just XOR-ing the bits with a random bit sequence (I dont need a very complex system). The linux host doesn't have C or PERL modules in it so I cant use them and hence I need to do it using a shell script. Can anyone please give me some pointers on how to proceed with this.

Also, if someone can suggest an alternate way to do this that would certainly be useful for me as well.

Cheers, Anshu

Comment: Have you tried [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org)?

Comment: Its missing in the linux host by default and since it doesnt have gcc, I am not able to install the gpg package directly. The linux host has just 11MBs of free memory so I am not able to install gcc in it as well.

Comment: Of course **you can do it**. You can use `dd` (in conjunction, for example, with `swap` option to provide a simple encrypting). In alternative you can use `read` in conjuction with `while` or `for` to do exactly what you ask (or, again, using `dd` to read, instead of `read`). I suppose there should be a way to do it with a short `sed` command but I'm not inside `sed` enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's not possible within the shell (Bash or similar), so you need an external program for that. Maybe the `hexdump` or `od` programs can do the reading for you, if they are available.

My suggestion: write a small C program for that, compile it using a cross-compiler, and run it from your shell script.

The `gpg` and `openssl` binaries can do encryption for you. I don't know how easy it is to compile or install them to your host.

Comment: Yeah, I had a C program written for it and I figured i will have to do some cross-compilation of it. But just wanted to see if I can do without the cross-compilation trouble. Thanks anyways for clearing it up .